# How to solve Oracle VM VirtualBox Windows 10 Installation Error ahci-0-1” (rc=verr_access_denied)?

Tags: virtualbox, window

I am trying to install Windows 10 to Virtual Machine from a bootable USB. The Virtual Box is opened as Administrator. In Windows setup when the drive to be selected it leads to an Error

> The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-2" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.
> Error ID:
> BLKCACHE_IOERR
> Severity:
> Non-Fatal Error

[Image: Windows Setup Error on Virtual Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14JWh.png)

Comment: I tried with an ISO file. It was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start VirtualBox with administrative permissions (Run as Administrator) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Is opened as Run as Administrator. And tried giving all permissions to the folder where Virtual Harddisk is saved.

Comment: I don't know what else it is, then. Can you try a different directory or something?

Comment: I tried that too..

Comment: I tried with an ISO file. It was successful.